# CIS Performance log

Tags: dxa, web8.5, model-service, cis

We are having problems in one of our environments related with CIS performance.
In DEV, the time consumed to retrieve a page is 1 second.
But in UAT, the same page expends 60 seconds.

Is there any log in CIS Services (Content and Model) that shows where the time is expended?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you accessing CIS services, through application/CIL or directly?
Is debug enabled for CIS services in UAT? (in logback.xml)

Comment: We are using postman to access directly to CIS services: http://server:8089/PageModel/tcm/41/en/index2.html?includes=INCLUDE

Comment: Today is working better. 2 seconds. One thing that I see is: - Content service: 200ms. same page thru Model Service: 2 seconds. It seems that model service is doing some stuff that add 1.8 seconds to the total time.